# R: Return rows with only 1 non-NA value for a set of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, magrittr

Suppose I have a data.table with the following data:

```
colA  colB  colC  result
1     2     3     231
1     NA    2     123
NA    3     NA    345
11    NA    NA    754
```

How would I use `dplyr` and `magrittr` to only select the following rows:

```
colA  colB  colC result
NA    3     NA   345
11    NA    NA   754
```

The selection criteria is: only 1 non-NA value for columns A-C (i.e. `colA, colB, ColC`)

I have been unable to find a similar question; guessing this is an odd situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A base R option would be

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)) == 1), ]
#  colA colB colC
#3   NA    3   NA
#4   11   NA   NA
```

A `dplyr` option is

```
df %>% filter(rowSums(!is.na(.)) == 1)
```

---

### Update

In response to your comment, you can do

```
df[apply(df[, -ncol(df)], 1, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)) == 1), ]
#  colA colB colC result
#3   NA    3   NA    345
#4   11   NA   NA    754
```

Or the same in `dplyr`

```
df %>% filter(rowSums(!is.na(.[-length(.)])) == 1)
```

This assumes that the last column is the one you'd like to ignore.

---

### Sample data

```
df <-read.table(text = "colA  colB  colC
1     2     3
1     NA    2
NA    3     NA
11    NA    NA", header = T)
```

### Sample data for update

```
df <- read.table(text =
"colA  colB  colC  result
1     2     3     231
1     NA    2     123
NA    3     NA    345
11    NA    NA    754
", header = T)
```

Comment: thanks, I knew there was a brilliant way. looking at your solution, i realize i needed to include another column to the MWE. basically, I'd only want 1 non-NA for a subset of all columns in my data.

Comment: @user2205916 I've updated my answer; please take a look.

Comment: brilliant again. is it easy to extend the answer if there are actually multiple columns I'd like to ignore and they are interspersed within the set of columns I'd like to filter? Regardless, this is a great point for me to start from.

Comment: @user2205916 Yes this is definitely extendable, the exact (code) details will depend on the data. It might be easiest to define an index vector of columns that are to be excluded, and then use that à la `df[, -idx_of_excluded_columns]` inside `apply` (or `rowSums(!is.na(.[-idx_of_excluded_columns]))` inside `dplyr::filter`).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `filter` with `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    filter(map(select(., starts_with('col')), ~ !is.na(.)) %>% 
              reduce(`+`) == 1)
#    colA colB colC result
#1   NA    3   NA    345
#2   11   NA   NA    754
```

---

Or another option is to use `transmute_at`

```
df %>% 
   transmute_at(vars(starts_with('col')), ~ !is.na(.)) %>% 
   reduce(`+`) %>%
   magrittr::equals(1) %>% filter(df, .)
#  colA colB colC result
#1   NA    3   NA    345
#2   11   NA   NA    754
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(colA = c(1L, 1L, NA, 11L), colB = c(2L, NA, 3L, 
NA), colC = c(3L, 2L, NA, NA), result = c(231L, 123L, 345L, 754L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be possible with `filter_at` but I was not able to make it work. Here is one attempt with `filter` and `pmap_lgl` where you can specify the range of columns in `select` or specify by their positions or use other tidyselect helper variables.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  filter(pmap_lgl(select(., colA:colC), ~sum(!is.na(c(...))) == 1))

 #  colA colB colC result
#1   NA    3   NA    345
#2   11   NA   NA    754
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(colA = c(1L, 1L, NA, 11L), colB = c(2L, NA, 3L, 
NA), colC = c(3L, 2L, NA, NA), result = c(231L, 123L, 345L, 754L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```